# Assigning values to pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a snippet of code I use:

```
void Move::AddToMovesList(Location* &list, int row, int col) {
    // If the list is empty, create the first item
    if (list == NULL)
        list = new Location(row, col);
    // List exists, so append
    else
        list->Add(row, col);
}
```

If `list` is `NULL`, a new `Location` should be created and the pointer `list` should point to that new location. That's the behavior I'd expect from this code, but right before gdb exits this function I noticed that `list` is still `NULL`. What am I doing wrong here?

I used the ampersand in `Location* &list` to make sure that I can permanently (vs. locally) change the supplied pointer.

Comment: Personally I would not use pointer. You are representing the empty list as the NULL pointer. That means you need to add code to explicitly check for this everywhere in your code. Create an object (that initially represents the empty list) then just add members to it no special case required.

Comment: Your code should work, did you turn off optimizations when debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you're talking about there, Vincent. I use gdb inside Eclipse with default settings. I'm on Windows and I use the MinGW C++ compiler.

Comment: i don't find anything wrong in your code. is list still NULL after returning from the function (i.e., it is still NULL from where you called it)? did you try `Location** list` and see what happens?

Comment: I think it will get much easier to think about once you fix your class names.  The word `Location` is singular, reading it does not make one think of a list.  Passing multiple arguments to a list constructor does not make one think that they will all be used to initialize one element and the resulting list will have length one.

Comment: @Donotalo: Weirdly, `list` is no longer `NULL` after returning from the function and it works without any problems. This debug output was captured right before exiting the function: `Name: list - Details:@0x22fea4 - Default:0x0`. Usually, Default and Details are the same. Why not here?

Comment: +1 to q for coming to the right place for help

Comment: @Ben: it's a dynamically linked list, so one `Location` object is linked to another. One `Location` object represents a location, not a list of locations. Therefore, I for one think it's more logical to use a singular word.

Comment: @Pieter: if a `Location` is not a list of locations, why is the parameter name `list`?  Perhaps `first` or `head` would better express the linked-list nature.  Other ways to deal with it would be naming the class `LocationListNode`, or changing the `add` function to accept a new `Location` to be linked in.

Comment: @Pieter: i've never used gdb. but i guess is that the debugger initializes uninitialized variables with 0x00. that's what `default` mean. and `details` is the actual address. since you're passing the pointer as a reference gdb didn't initialize it with `0x00`. that's why they are different. whatever i've just talked about is completely by guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not reinvent the wheel here... [Know your libraries.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)

If you use the STL list container (or any other container) then you don't need to bother with null pointers.

Comment: I'm doing this for a school project and we've not covered lists in our C++ course so far, so unfortunately I'm not allowed to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not use pointer at all.

```
class Location
{
    public:
        void add(int row, int col)
        {
            data.push_back(std::make_pair(row,col));
        }
        bool isEmpty()  const {return data.empty(); }
    private:
        std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > data;
};


class Move
{
    public:
        // Pass a reference to the list.
        // No special case processing if the list is empty.
        // No problems with ownership.
        // No problems with lifespan associated with new/delete
        void addToMoveList(Location& list, int row, int col)
        {
            list.add(row, col);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Location    list;  // Don't use new if you can declare a local variable.
    Move        move;

    move.addToMoveList(list, 10, 2);
}
```

Comment: Looks much easier to implement, but as I mentioned in another comment I'm doing a school project on C++ and we've hardly covered any C++-specific advantages. I'm not allowed to use stuff we haven't covered in the project, so for now I think I have to stick to the C alternative of creating dynamically linked lists.

Comment: @Pieter - you may not be allowed to use STL etc, but still you don't have to do it in C fashion, with brute-force memory management via new/delete/malloc/free and raw pointers everywhere.